# asynchronous operation with recyclerview and asynctask in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-asynctask, xamarin.android

i just started to work on performance in mobile app development and i am using asynctask. but i encounter a few challenges, whenever i instantiate my recyclerview in the oncreate method of my activity and retrieve data through async task, i then try to update the recyclerview adapter but it doesn't work. Here's my code below. Here's my activity below

```
public class awarenessActivity : Activity
{
    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
    public List<AwarePosts> awrPosts;

    ScrollView tabsitem;
    ImageButton aware;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //preparing the datasource
        awrPosts = new List<AwarePosts>();//empty for now, its the data that i'm trying to retrieve with asynctask

        //setting view from Layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        //get the linearlayout from the layout resource
        tabsitem = (ScrollView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.scrollView1);
        tabsitem.RemoveAllViews();
        LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.awareness, tabsitem);

        //this adds this layout to the main page
        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

        //Create our layoutManager
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.NestedScrollingEnabled = false;

        //instantiate the adapter and pass in it the datasource
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(awrPosts);
        mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        //plug the adapter into the recycler view
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

        new retrievePosts(this).Execute();//executing the asynctask

        ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// these are for the back arrow item

    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.ItemId;

        if (id == global::Android.Resource.Id.Home)
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(menuActivity));
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void OnItemClick(object sender, int position)
    {
        string img, author, caption, info, postid, link, videolink;
        try
        {
            img = awrPosts[position].image;
            author = awrPosts[position].author;
            caption = awrPosts[position].title;
            info = awrPosts[position].externaL_LINK;
            postid = awrPosts[position].awarenesS_EVENT_ID.ToString();
            link = awrPosts[position].externaL_LINK;
            videolink = awrPosts[position].videO_LINK;

            string[] arr = new string[] { img.ToString(), author, caption, info, postid, link, videolink };
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            Intent awareDetailInt = new Intent(this, typeof(awareDetailActivity));

            b.PutStringArray("array", arr);
            awareDetailInt.PutExtras(b);
            StartActivity(awareDetailInt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Finish();
    }

    internal List<AwarePosts> getPosts(List<string> imag)
    {
        List<AwarePosts> ap = new List<AwarePosts>();
        try
        {
            ap.Add(new AwarePosts()
            {
                awarenesS_EVENT_ID = 1,
                gendeR_TARGET = 2,
                image = imag.ElementAt(0),
                title = "Are you Happy?",
                author = "casual optimist",
                videO_LINK = "",
                externaL_LINK = "",
                agE_TARGET_MIN = 5,
                agE_TARGET_MAX = 9,
                creatioN_DATE = "",
                creatioN_USER = ""
            });

            ap.Add(new AwarePosts()
            {
                awarenesS_EVENT_ID = 2,
                gendeR_TARGET = 2,
                image = imag.ElementAt(1),
                title = "Positive Vibes",
                author = "etsy",
                videO_LINK = "",
                externaL_LINK = "",
                agE_TARGET_MIN = 5,
                agE_TARGET_MAX = 9,
                creatioN_DATE = "",
                creatioN_USER = ""
            });
            ap.Add(new AwarePosts()
            {
                awarenesS_EVENT_ID = 3,
                gendeR_TARGET = 2,
                image = imag.ElementAt(2),
                title = "30+ funny comics",
                author = "jimmy benton",
                videO_LINK = "",
                externaL_LINK = "",
                agE_TARGET_MIN = 5,
                agE_TARGET_MAX = 9,
                creatioN_DATE = "",
                creatioN_USER = ""
            });
            ap.Add(new AwarePosts()
            {
                awarenesS_EVENT_ID = 4,
                gendeR_TARGET = 2,
                image = imag.ElementAt(3),
                title = "Smiling Doodle",
                author = "instagram",
                videO_LINK = "",
                externaL_LINK = "",
                agE_TARGET_MIN = 5,
                agE_TARGET_MAX = 9,
                creatioN_DATE = "",
                creatioN_USER = ""
            });
            ap.Add(new AwarePosts()
            {
                awarenesS_EVENT_ID = 5,
                gendeR_TARGET = 2,
                image = imag.ElementAt(4),
                title = "Have a good day",
                author = "society6",
                videO_LINK = "",
                externaL_LINK = "",
                agE_TARGET_MIN = 5,
                agE_TARGET_MAX = 9,
                creatioN_DATE = "",
                creatioN_USER = ""
            });

            return ap;
        }
        catch (WebException web)
        {
            ap.Add(new AwarePosts { title = web.Response.ToString() });
            return ap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ap.Add(new AwarePosts { title = ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace});
            return ap;
        }
    }

    public List<string> drawableImageToBase64String(Context context)//doing some local data collection here
    {
        List<string> images = new List<string>();
        int[] imgs = new int[] { Resource.Drawable.first1, Resource.Drawable.second1, Resource.Drawable.third1, Resource.Drawable.fourth1, Resource.Drawable.fifth2 };
        foreach(var item in imgs)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, item);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            byte[] ba = stream.ToArray();
            string bal = Convert.ToBase64String(ba);
            images.Add(bal);
        }            
        return images;
    }
}
```

here's my edited asynctask code

```
public class retrievePosts : AsyncTask<Java.Lang.Void, Java.Lang.Void, List<AwarePosts>>
{
    awarenessActivity aw;
    List<AwarePosts> awr;
    Context mContext;
    RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
    public retrievePosts(awarenessActivity awre, Context context, RecyclerAdapter adapter)
    {
        aw = awre;
        mContext = context;
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Shared.ShowImage(mContext, Resource.Drawable.load2, "Getting Posts...");
    }

    protected override List<AwarePosts> RunInBackground(Java.Lang.Void[] @params)
    {
        List<string> img = aw.drawableImageToBase64String(mContext); 
        awr = aw.getPosts(img);
        return awr;
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(List<AwarePosts> result)
    {
        base.OnPostExecute(result);        
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(result);
        mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Shared.Dismiss(mContext);
        Toast.MakeText(mContext, "successful", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

and i'm calling it with this

```
awarenessActivity aw;

    ScrollView tabsitem;
    ImageButton aware;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //preparing the datasource
        aw = new awarenessActivity();
        awrPosts = new List<AwarePosts>();

        //set our view from the "Playlist" Layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        //get the linearlayout from the layout resource
        tabsitem = (ScrollView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.scrollView1);
        tabsitem.RemoveAllViews();
        LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.awareness, tabsitem);

        //this adds this layout to the main page
        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

        //Create our layoutManager
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.NestedScrollingEnabled = false;

        //instantiate the adapter and pass in it the datasource
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(awrPosts);
        mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        //plug the adapter into the recycler view
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

        new retrievePosts(aw, this, mAdapter).Execute();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did wrong to new a `awarenessActivity` in your `retrievePosts`, you can pass the `mAdapter` as parameter to your `retrievePosts`, try to modify your `retrievePosts` like this:

```
public class retrievePosts : AsyncTask<string, string, List<AwarePosts>>
{
    List<AwarePosts> awr;
    Context mContext;
    RecyclerAdapter mAdapter
    public retrievePosts(Context context, RecyclerAdapter adapter)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Shared.ShowImage(mContext, Resource.Drawable.load2, "Getting Posts...");
    }

    protected override List<AwarePosts> RunInBackground(params string[] @params)
    {
        List<string> img = aw.drawableImageToBase64String(mContext); 
        //not sure what are you doing here, if you want to get some objects from your awarenessActivity, still try to make it as a parameter and pass to here.
        return awr;
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(List<AwarePosts> result)// this function is supposed to run on the UI thread
    {
        base.OnPostExecute(result);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(result); // assigning the data here
        mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();//y'all kn what i'm trying to do here
        AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Shared.Dismiss(mContext);
        Toast.MakeText(mContext, "successful", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

And when you use it, try like this `new retrievePosts(this, mAdapter).Execute();`.

I didn't test this code, but it should be something like it. I noticed that in your `RunInBackground` method, you also tried to get some object from the `awarenessActivity`, try to pass it like `RecyclerAdapter` here as parameter to this class. Don't create a new Activity in it.

Comment: on the line you commented "not sure what are doing here, i am calling the function that is supposed to bring the data from the API."

Comment: @IsraelEruoghene, it's OK, just don't create a new instance of your activity and try to get data from this activity.

Comment: still didn't work, infact now my onpostexecute isn't being called at all, but doinbackground gets called and returns proper result. i have done all u said

Comment: @IsraelEruoghene, you can call your `onpostexecute` method in the constructor of `retrievePosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got it to work @grace Feng's answer was correct. i just didn't set the recycler view adapter inside the onpostexecute method after `mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();`

after adding this line, it worked and my recycler view was populated. Thanks grace feng

```
mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
```